# angular ng-click inside ng-repeat to update $scope and then use $apply to update dom

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular 1.2

ng-repeat creates divs that also contain ng-click

ng-click updates $scope when clicked

the change in $scope is reflected in ng-repeat using $apply

It works ... but I get an error when I click and I think I am applying $apply incorrectly

here is my [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/PrimeLens/Pa242/)

```
function appcontrol ($scope, $log) {
  // declare $scope vars
  $scope.currentlist = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $scope.currentlist[i] = {'key':i, 'value':i};  
  }
  $scope.extra = 'My Extra';
  $scope.anotherextra = 'Another Extra';
  // click handler
  $scope.handleCellClick = function(cellnumber){
    $log.log(cellnumber + ' clicked');
    // update the $scope property
    $scope.currentlist[cellnumber].value = 'AAA';
    // push out the new change to the dom
    $scope.$apply();    
    // trigger other stuff
  }
  // click handler
  $scope.handleExtraClick = function(arg){
    $log.log('extra clicked  ', arg);
    // update the $scope property
    if (arg=='My Extra') $scope.extra = 'AAA';
    if (arg=='Another Extra') $scope.anotherextra = 'AAA';
    // push out the new change to the dom
    $scope.$apply();    
    // trigger other stuff
  }         
}
```

and html

```
 <div ng-controller="appcontrol">
   <div ng-repeat="item in currentlist" id="cell{{item.value}}" ng-model="item.value" class="cell" ng-click="handleCellClick(item.key)">{{item.value}}</div>
   <div id="cell{{extra}}" ng-click="handleExtraClick(extra)">{{extra}}</div>
   <div id="cell{{anotherextra}}" ng-click="handleExtraClick(anotherextra)">{{anotherextra}}</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular already call `$apply` for you when you use `ng-click`. If you take out all the `$scope.$apply()` in your code, the error won't show up, and it would work exactly the same. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pa242/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `$scope.$apply()` way you are using it. AngularJS loads the data in `$scope` automatically. `$apply()` is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. Also, I would use this function very sparely as it slows your performance.

For example, you would use `$apply()` for data changed outside of angular like this:

```
//explicitly auto adjust width and height when user changes size
$scope.$apply( function(){              
    $scope.width = $window.innerWidth;
    $scope.height = $window.innerHeight;                            
});
```

Checkout more here--> [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply)